# Set database object to be deleted in android

Tags: android, database

I've setup a database in android for my app however I'm stuck trying to delete a object within the database.
 I'd like the button within  BasicButtonsCard to delete the item that has been clicked on. 
For example cardX holds data ABCD while cardY hold EFGH and on clicking the delete button on cardX, it deletes the card and its data.

Help is appreciated.

Code for input field:

```
public class note extends DialogFragment {

EditText memoryText, memoryTitle;

public interface NewPersonDialogListener{
    void onFinishAddPersonDialog(String text, String title);
}

public note(){}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    LayoutInflater i = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View rootview = i.inflate(R.layout.activity_note, null);

    memoryText = (EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.memoryText);
    memoryTitle = (EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.memoryTitle);

    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    b.setTitle("Add New Memory");
    b.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            String text = memoryText.getText().toString();
            String title = memoryTitle.getText().toString();

            NewPersonDialogListener activity = (NewPersonDialogListener)getActivity();
            activity.onFinishAddPersonDialog(text, title);
        }
    });
    b.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    b.setView(rootview);
    return b.create();


}

}
```

Code that handles MainActivity in the app:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements note.NewPersonDialogListener{

ImageButton runCommand;
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ListView mDrawerList;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
String[] mDrawerListItems;
MaterialListView mListView;
MemoryDataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    dataSource = new MemoryDataSource(this);

    mListView = (MaterialListView) findViewById(R.id.material_listview);
    generateList();

    mListView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(CardItemView cardItemView, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(CardItemView cardItemView, int i) {

        }
    });




    mDrawerListItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_list);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDrawerListItems));

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {

                case 0:

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case 1:

                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, bands.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:

                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, memory_vault.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

            }
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    });


    runCommand = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.runCommand);
    runCommand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            /*
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, note.class);
            startActivity(i);
            */
            note noteFragment = new note();
            noteFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");


        }
    });

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close){
        public void onDrawerClosed(View v){
            super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }
        public void onDrawerOpened(View v){
            super.onDrawerOpened(v);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

}

public void generateList(){
    dataSource.open();
    List<memoryModel> list = dataSource.findMemory();
    for (memoryModel model : list){
        BasicButtonsCard card = new BasicButtonsCard(this);
        card.setTitle(model.getmemoryTitle());
        card.setDescription(model.getmemoryText());
        card.setBackgroundColorRes(R.color.background_material_dark);
        card.setDescriptionColorRes(R.color.abc_secondary_text_material_dark);
        card.setTitleColorRes(R.color.abc_secondary_text_material_dark);
        card.setLeftButtonText("LEFT");
        card.setRightButtonText("RIGHT");
        card.setDismissible(true);


        card.setOnRightButtonPressedListener(new OnButtonPressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onButtonPressedListener(View view, Card card) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, bands.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        card.setOnLeftButtonPressedListener(new OnButtonPressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onButtonPressedListener(View view, Card card) {

            }
        });

        mListView.add(card);
    }
}


@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home: {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
            return true;
        }
        default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


@Override
public void onFinishAddPersonDialog(String text, String title) {
    dataSource.open();
    memoryModel model = new memoryModel();
    model.setmemoryText(title);
    model.setmemoryTitle(text);
    dataSource.create(model);
    dataSource.close();
    generateList();
}
}
```

Comment: i dont understand how to implement dataSource.deleteMemory(); in this situation

Comment: What is `MemoryDataSource` ?  Do you need to know how to delete from a sqlite database, or something else?

Comment: no im not very familiar with deleting from databases, memory datasource holds functions like create delete open and close

Comment: I would start with the delete method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: it is what i'm trying i already understand the process i just dont know how to implement

Comment: Do you have a database helper already (a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper)?  If not, look up an android sqlite tutorial and do that.  If you're having trouble with that part, I would delete this question and post a new one with your specific difficulty.  If you have the helper class, use that to get a reference to SqliteDatabase and call the delete method.  Is there something about the delete method you don't understand?

Comment: i already have a database helper that has a delete method my problem is having to implement a delete method in this case since onclick listener for listview would affect all cards i cant use it so i'm using a indiviudal button for each card to call the delete method and that is where i am stuck

Comment: You're not having trouble "implementing" a delete method - you don't need to implement it, you just need to call it. So you're stuck how?  You don't know how to put a button on a listview row?  Don't know how to assign a listener to it? Don't know how to call delete from the listener?  If you want to get help, you need to be specific about what it is you're having trouble with.

Comment: i dont know how to call it assign a listener and call delete from listener , sorry that i sound so vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue of deleting data from the database. Since it was contained in a cardview layout with a button all I needed to do was add a onclick listener which would do the following

```
dataSource.deleteMemory(model.getmemoryTitle());
dataSource.deleteMemory(model.getmemoryText());
mListView.remove(card);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you already have a RecyclerView with a button on each row since you didn't mention that as a problem.  You should have a view holder class, and in the constructor of that class you can set up your listeners.

```
class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            public Holder(View itemView){
                super(itemView);

                View button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        int rowNumber = getPosition();
                        // call delete method here

                    }
                });
    }
    public void bind(int index){
        // ...
    }
}
```